# Send Model Data through AJAX in Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to send a model data through ajax in django.

My view.py is like this.

```
from django.core import serializers
def country(request):
    country = NewTable.objects.get(id=1)
    data = serializers.serialize('json',country)
    return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/json')
```

My url.py is like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^country/$', views.country) 

)
```

my template is like this

```
    function Country(){

    $.get('/myapp/country', function(data) {
    alert("hello");
}, "json" );

}
```

when i send the string through view i get the alert message now when I am sending the model data I don't get any alert message.what is the problem?

Comment: Is the server returning a 500 response? You can see this in the network profiler of the Chrome developer tools or in the terminal where runserver is running.

Comment: Yes it is returning a 500 response

Comment: What's the exception then? The error message and the stack trace will be helpful.

Comment: "GET /myapp/country/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11258

Comment: you should swap mimetype for content_type, as described in basically every post on stackexchange about returning json objects with django. not that doing so will actually solve the problem, but you may as well do it the same way that everyone else does for ease of troubleshooting.

Comment: @user3614894 You're getting a 500 response because an exception is being thrown. Please find out what that exception is and include the stacktrace in your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues, and instead of django's serializers I switched to using json.dumps and now everything works fine.

view.py

```
import json
def country(request):
    country = NewTable.objects.filter(id=1).values()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(country),content_type='application/json')
```

EDIT: I am not sure you can use get() for values(), i am using filter in my code and that might be why yours isnt working

Comment: I get the following error 'NewTable' object has no attribute 'values',what do you import for values()?

Comment: I dont import anything, what version of Django are you using? Here is the documentation for it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: I think I see what happened, edited my answer to work correctly

Comment: thanks for your help.I still get the error ."is not JSON serializable".I've found the solution though

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution

view.py

```
from django.core import serializers
import json
    def country(request):
    obj_json = serializers.serialize('json', NewTable.objects.filter(id=1) )
    obj_list = json.loads( obj_json )
    json_data = json.dumps( obj_list )
    return HttpResponse( json_data, mimetype='application/json' )
```

template

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url:"/myapp/country",
success: function(data)
{
    alert("Hello");
},
```

});